# Calculate mean, max, min number of observations per group in R

Tags: r

How to calculate mean, max, and min **number of reviews** per group in a dataframe in R? I have a dataset that looks like below:

```
Firm Review 
  A   Nice work
  B   Ok
  C   yes
  A   ok
  B   yes
  A   like
```

In this case, firm A has 3 reviews, B has 2 and C has 1. Then Max=3, min=1, and average number of review per firm =6/3=2.
The actual dataset has 2.1 million reviews across 50000 firms. What would be an effective way to group by a firm and then calculate these statistics?

Comment: How do you wish to calculate mean for Review ?

Comment: I cannot understand! Do you want NLP segregation of these reviews? If not, what does Min, max mean, I am unable to understand?  It will be better if you could add a sample output.

Comment: `summary(as.numeric(table(your_data$Firm)))` will give you min, max, quartiles, and mean number of rows per firm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally use `dplyr` for this kind of thing if I understand you correctly.

```
    firm_reviews %>% 
        group_by(firm) %>% 
        count() %>% 
        ungroup() %>% 
        summarise(mean(n), min(n), max(n))
```

Comment: If n is same for a group, what will mean/max/min refer here, I am unable to understand?? All will just be equal to n only

Comment: count() produces counts for the number of responses to each firm. These counts are given in a data frame with a column labeled 'n' that lists the number of responses for each firm. Using summarize applies the functions mean, min, and max to this column of counts.

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what i am trying to explain.  Lets assume count of reviews for firm A is 50.  Count() will add this value 50 against each A.  Now what will mean/max/min of these values.  All will be 50.  Which is meaningless

Comment: Unless I misunderstand you, this is not the case because group_by causes counts to be specific to each firm. The data frame of counts will have as many rows as you have firms and as many counts of of reviews as you have firms. Then summarizing will produce the results you are looking for.

Comment: Please read the question, in that case.  The user wants to know min/max/mean number of reviews per group.  Whereas you are trying to calculate these stats for whole data.  On the other hand, your query is group_by on firm.  So the results you are expecting won't be produced by the query.  See it on any sample data of your choice.  All min/max/mean will be equal to n for every group i.e. firm.

Comment: As you are insisting, I just tried your code and found that all min/max/mean are all equal, I am saying